# Google Analytics API Javascript v4 event tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to pull the number of times a certain event (by the event-action) fired with the Google Analytics v4 Javascript API. What do I need to put in the filter section to get the number that I'm looking for? This is what I have now and it's just returning zero:

```
// Call the Analytics Reporting API V4 batchGet method.
        gapi.client.analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet( {
          "reportRequests":[
          {
            "viewId":VIEW_ID,
            "dateRanges":[
              {
                "startDate":"yesterday",
                "endDate":"today"
              }],
            "metrics":[
              {
                "expression":"ga:totalEvents"
              }],
            "dimensions": [{"name":"ga:eventLabel"}],
            "dimensionFilterClauses": [
              {
                "filters": [
                  {
                    "dimensionName": "ga:eventLabel",
                    "operator": "EXACT",
                    "expressions": ["name-of-label"]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
          }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request appears to be correct:

```
{
  "reportRequests": 
  [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXX",
      "dimensions": 
      [
        {
          "name": "ga:eventLabel"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": 
      [
        {
          "expression": "ga:totalEvents"
        }
      ],
      "dimensionFilterClauses": 
      [
        {
          "filters": 
          [
            {
              "operator": "EXACT",
              "dimensionName": "ga:eventLabel",
              "expressions": ["name-of-label"]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Ruling everything out I would suggest making the request without the filter to ensure that you have the full string `name-of-label`. If you only have a partial string then use a different [operator](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#Operator):

- `BEGINS_WITH`    Matches the values which begin with the match expression
  provided.
- `ENDS_WITH`  Matches the values which end with the match
  expression provided.
- `PARTIAL`    Substring match.
- ...